# Can I force GMail to not load large sets of data (attachments/images) when using mobile data?

Tags: gmail, mobile-data

I just noticed that GMail loaded 60-70MB data the last 2 days, in ~15 minute period. It was using my (limited) mobile data plan to do this.

This was around the time I was opening large email threads with images (HOWEVER, the images were old and not part of new emails I was reading).

Is there a way to configure GMail so that it does NOT download large data (especially images/attachments) in old messages in a thread I'm opening, unless I explicitly open the message that contains the image/attachment? I'm fine if that setting is "non-WiFi only" or "100% time".

I'm using the latest GMail app from the store (whatever the current version in App Store is as of October 2015).

OS shouldn't matter to the answer but it's rooted Android 4.3 on Samsung Galaxy Note 3.

Comment: As far as I know, attachments aren't downloaded with mobile data, only on wifi. To prevent gmail to download images in the body of the mails try: settings -> tap on your account's email -> images -> ask before showing.

Comment: You can use K9 mail (open source) to accomplish all that and more. Unlimited download size, filters, sorting, smaller apk size,.....I know its not the solution you want (thats why its a comment), but it is a viable option